# Android:Dropbox implementation

Tags: android, dropbox

Are dropbox APIs open for android? 
Can I integrate dropbox in an android application. The online documentation is really bad. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Android Dropbox SDK can be found here: http://www.dropbox.com/developers/releases. Usage documentation is here: http://www.dropbox.com/developers/docs.